# Selection of port for HTTPs based URL

Tags: ports

I have an application and it will be exposed to HTTPs based URL. I want to put a port explicitly. So if I do I can select 8443 port.

```
https://<IP_ADDRESS>:8443/myApplication
```

If I don't put a port explicitly then the port will 443.

```
https://<IP_ADDRESS>/myApplication
```

What other port I can use? Can I use any port? For example 8554 (random guess).

Comment: Any port above 1024 should work fine for a normal user account running a web server. Ports below 1024 are usually considered privileged, and normal users are not typically allowed to run services on them. For more information, see, for example, this website: https://www.w3.org/Daemon/User/Installation/PrivilegedPorts.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What other port I can use? Can I use any port? For example 8554 (random guess).

Any port above 1024 should work fine for a normal user account running a web server. So, 8554 should work for you.

Ports below 1024 are usually considered privileged, and normal users are not typically allowed to run services on them. For more information, see, for example, [this](http://w3.org/Daemon/User/Installation/PrivilegedPorts.html) website, that explains more about how privileged services can listen on port 80 or 443, but unprivileged users should do their testing on higher ports.

> If I don't put a port explicitly then the port will 443. https://<IP_ADDRESS>/myApplication

Yes, the default HTTPS port is port 443. For testing, you can use almost whatever port you like (typically above port 1024).

Comment: Thanks, my understanding about this is right? For a URL like this: https://<IP_ADDRESS>/myApplication the port is 443?

Comment: The port for HTTPS is 443, yes. The port for HTTP is 80. You can search for IANA Port Numbers to get a list of registered ports.

Comment: Yes, the default HTTPS port is 443. I updated the answer to also address this question.

Answer (score 2):

You can, in theory, use any value that fits in a 16-bit integer (that is, any number below 65536) as a TCP port, if it isn't in use for anything else. However, there are some caveats:

1. Low ports (below 1024) are reserved for specific services, and also are restricted by the operating system. You can't create a server listening on those ports without special kernel permissions (typically, the server just starts as the root/admin user, and potentially lowers its privileges after it starts listening). However, any process can send a message *to* such ports (obviously, otherwise your web browser couldn't connect to normal HTTP or HTTPS servers, which listen on 80 and 443 respectively).
2. Some ports outside of that range might still be used for various services. If you have any such servers on your machine, they'll be using those ports.
3. When a program establishes an *outbound* connection, this also consumes a port (after all, the program needs to be be able to tell its peer what port to use when sending messages back). These ["ephemeral" ports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port) are dynamically and automatically allocated by the operating system from the range of valid port numbers, and it's a bad idea to specifically use them for anything because any time you try to start listening on that port, if some outbound connection is using it, your server will fail to start. The range of dynamically allocated ports varies by operating system, but on [modern Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/service-overview-and-network-port-requirements) and [MacOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46023485/what-is-the-range-of-ephemeral-ports-on-mac) it's any port equal to or above 49152, and on many Linux kernels it's 32768-60999 (inclusive).

Thus, for maximum compatibility, your application should probably listen on ports in the range of at least 5001 (or at least 1025 if you don't care about pre-Vista Windows, which honestly you shouldn't) to 32767 (assuming you don't want to use the standard HTTPS port of 443, which requires privileges since it's below 1024), and you should also check whatever port you choose to make sure it's not used by anything else running on your server.